# WordPress -Mainintaing URL parameters

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-parameters

I have created a custom table namely **company** Now I want to load respective company's details based on URL

I am thinking of creating URL such as `example.com/?company=1` and `example.com/?company=1&depart=2`

Now after login employee will be redirected to its respected company URL. 
Now based on company URL (`$_GET['company']` )I will be setting some global vars which will contain company details such as COMPANY_NAME so that I can access on any page.

With this approach I have to maintain the URL parameters on every page load/redirect. And also maintain global vars.
Please tell me if this is a good approach or if there is any other better way. I don't want to use multisite.

I have started with using query vars

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'addnew_query_vars' );
function addnew_query_vars($vars)
{   
    $vars[] = 'company'; 
    $vars[] = 'depart';     
    return $vars;

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'setVars' );
function setVars()
{   
    if($_GET['company']){
        set_query_var( 'store',$_GET['company'] );
    }else{
        set_query_var( 'company',2 );
    }
    if($_GET['depart']){
        set_query_var( 'depart',$_GET['depart'] );
    }else{
        set_query_var( 'depart',2 );
    } 

}
```

If parameters are set in the URL then it will get that param values else it will take the default one (i.e 2 )

**Edit**

- I need to create URLs for each company so that I can send to clients,therefore I have to use URL parameters anyway

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's an old approach, now a days, Wordpress and php even all technologies are very flexible, they provide thousands of different ways to do the same thing.
For your approach, best way is to do the things using Wordpress query param, which is a modified way to make an awesome url.
If you don't prefer to share the company ids on the url then try using php session, which is also a good practise and also you have secure data. but with session you will not be able to share the url, so best way is to use the query param.

Comment: Do you mean query_vars. Please check the code in question I have updated.

Comment: I have to create URLs for each company so that I can send to clients,therefore I cannot use sessions

Comment: Use this approach, but what I meant is instead of using URL like: example.com/?company=1 and example.com/?company=1&depart=2, You should use like this: example.com/company/company_id/department/department_id. Instead of department id and company id use there slug, so your url will look more beautiful and will be SEO friendly.

Comment: How to get this kind of link (example.com/company/company_id/department/department_id) and how it will be fetched ?

Comment: Read this article and you will understand, how query_var in Wordpress work and how to make beautiful URLs and how to fetch them. https://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/post/custom-query-string-vars-in-wordpress